# How to upload a text file to a window in Kivi, Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, kivy, text-files

Hellow, I need my application to receive a text file by 'dragging and dropping'. It is fundamentally important that the place where I will drag the file is in the application window.

Comment: Have a look at [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase}. Specifically, `on_drop_file`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many time has passed

To upload file you need:

Make Window.bind(on_drop_file=self.onFileDrop)

```
def build(self):
   Window.bind(on_drop_file=self.onFileDrop)
```

where 'on_drop_file' is name of Event, what will be with your window
onFileDrop is function, witch you use

```
def onFileDrop(self, window, file_path, *agrs):
   #type(file_path) = bytes
```

have a good day :)